# Azure, shut down all vm's when out of money

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, shutdown, currency

I need to stop all my vm's in azure portal when my balance is 0$ How can i do it? maybe some script?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't do that with script for now... The balance (or billing) is not exposed via the [Azure REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ee460799.aspx) (or [Azure PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/jj156055.aspx)).

Comment: Hallo! Ty for answer! Maybe it is some solution to run shut down script when i got billing alert from azure?

Comment: Yes, you can try to run a script when a billing alert mail arrives in your mail server...  it might work in theory :)

Comment: for script on email, we have used IMAP with success in the past. NICE easy c# API (I forget the .NET API we used, but there are plenty).. but you might be able to interact with the alerts (not tried myself) http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2014/11/08/scripts-to-tools-automate-monitoring-alert-rules-in-microsoft-azure-with-powershell-and-the-azure-service-management-rest-api.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For shutdown, we use a RUNBOOK with the follow code inside.

We run this everyday at 8PM. (You could trigger this from another alert http://www.matthewjbailey.com/create-azure-billing-alert-email/)

```
workflow ShutDown-AllVMs {
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String] $VMCredentialName = "ourcred@xyz.com"
    )

        $Credential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name $VMCredentialName 

        if ($Credential -eq $null)  {
            throw "Could not retrieve '$VMCredentialName' credential asset. Check that you created this asset in the Automation service."
        }     

        Add-AzureAccount -Credential $Credential

        Select-AzureSubscription BizSpark

        InlineScript {            
            Get-azurevm | ? { $_.Status -ne "StoppedDeallocated"}  | Stop-AzureVM -Force               
        }
}
```

For alerts

Setup the alert

http://www.matthewjbailey.com/create-azure-billing-alert-email/

Monitor the alert

http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2014/11/08/scripts-to-tools-automate-monitoring-alert-rules-in-microsoft-azure-with-powershell-and-the-azure-service-management-rest-api.aspx

I have not tried all this together, so you may have a 2+2=5 issue :) but have a read of the blogs and you may find that you get 4 :)

Comment: Hi! Ty for answer! I know abot this kind  of script, but i need to shut down my vm when my ballance is about 0$.

Comment: ok, does this help http://www.matthewjbailey.com/create-azure-billing-alert-email/